# Xamarin Forms - Make custom cell bind to original listview itemsource when calling event "ItemSelected"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, itemsource

I have searched around and I dont think I am finding the answer to my question. I am new to xamarin so i hope I am using the correct terminology. I am experimenting with custom cells in listviews. My aim is to reuse the custom cell throughout multiple parts of my application but when I use the event "ItemSelected" it comes back with the bindings to the custom cell and not my original listview itemsource bindings. I understand why I think but I am unsure how to bind the ItemSelected to the original source. Am I using the right method here? I am completely lost if I am honest.

This is my custom cell code:

```
public partial class ListCell : ViewCell
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty LabelHeaderProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelHeader", typeof(string), typeof(ListCell));
        public string LabelHeader
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelHeaderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelHeaderProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty LabelSmallProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelSmall", typeof(string), typeof(ListCell));
        public string LabelSmall
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelSmallProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelSmallProperty, value); }
        }
        public ListCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            BindingContext = new
            {
                LabelHeader = this.LabelHeader,
                LabelSmall = this.LabelSmall
            };
        }
    }
```

Here is my ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
                SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <extensions:ListCell LabelHeader="{Binding Description}"
                                         LabelSmall="{Binding Description}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, when binding to a custom cell type's `BindableProperty` instances, the UI controls displaying the `BindableProperty` values should use the `OnBindingContextChanged` override to set the data to be displayed in each cell.

```
 public class ListCell:ViewCell
{
    Label headerLabel, smallLabel;
    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelHeaderProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelHeader", typeof(string), typeof(ListCell),"name");
    public string LabelHeader
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelHeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelHeaderProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelSmallProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelSmall", typeof(string), typeof(ListCell),"small label");
    public string LabelSmall
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelSmallProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelSmallProperty, value); }
    }

    public ListCell()
    {
        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout { Orientation=StackOrientation.Horizontal};
        headerLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
        smallLabel = new Label();
        stack.Children.Add(headerLabel);
        stack.Children.Add(smallLabel);
        View = stack;
    }
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        if (BindingContext != null)
        {
            headerLabel.Text = LabelHeader;
            smallLabel.Text = LabelSmall;
           
        }
    }
}

 <ListView
            x:Name="listView"
            ItemSelected="listView_ItemSelected"
            ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ListCell LabelHeader="{Binding Name}" LabelSmall="{Binding description}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

But You can use [TextCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#textcell) in ListView's DataTemplate directly, don't need to create custom viewcell.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Detail="{Binding description}" Text="{Binding name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

About using TextCell, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#binding-cells

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I am using a custom cell is because of the reuse of the layout I require of the cell. Apologies, I didn't include that xaml in this post for clarification. Your solution has fixed my issue though but I just used x:Name in the xaml file to set headerLabel and smallLabel to avoid in code xaml building. One question however, I noticed you left InitializeComponent(); out in your constructor. Is there a drawback to it being there? Are there times I shouldn't use it? Thanks again

Comment: @Tanya you can see that I create class name ListCell, inherit ViewCell, `InitializeComponent()` generally exists in the constructor of the page .